# Xtify - Not Receiving Push Notifications - Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xtify

Trying to get Xtify working on Android, but not having any luck.

I have successfully ran the demo and can receive push notifications with that.  But I'm not getting them on my own app.

The device gets successfully registered, and I've copied everything exactly from the Demo app... Made sure all the permissions/services/receievers were set in the manifest.

Anybody got any ideas as to why it isn't working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.... I didn't realize that you `must have a separate API Project for each application.`

All the headache for nothing!